# Можно ли как-то задать глобольную переменную в **php.ini**?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, php.ini

Можно ли как-то задать переменную в **php.ini** так чтобы везде во всех **php** скриптах можно было её использовать как обычную **$str22** например? *(инклуд не подходит, нужно глобально задать)*

Comment: т.е. создать суперглобальную переменную, но чтобы использовать можно было как обычную, а не как массив. $_SERVER, $_ENV не подходит. Нужно чтобы без приставки. Можно было задать произвольную переменную.

Comment: Как вариант можно задать константу http://php.net/const

Comment: посмотрите опцию auto_prepend_file в php.ini она позволяет задать скрипт, который будет автоматически загружаться перед выполнением любого другого php скрипта, как будто любой скрипт в системе первой строкой делает include этого скрипта. В нем вы можете задать все что угодно, включая конечно и глобальные переменные